# How To Modify PKCS11 Object Value Attribute

Tags: cryptography, smartcard, pkcs#11, hardware-security-module, nitrokey

I have a Nitrokey HSM 2 which I am using python-pkcs11 to interface with via a Python3 program. I have an object of class type `pkcs11.ObjectClass.DATA` on the HSM whose `Attribute.VALUE` I would like to update often since I am using it as a sort of data storage.

So far, the only way I can find to do this is by deleting the object entirely and re-creating it, but this adds too much overhead since this causes the operations to run for 10x longer.

What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is inpossible due to limitations in the implementation of [PKCS#11 library](https://github.com/Nitrokey/nethsm-pkcs11/blob/13fa4922102ccec4f8c521e89d1c6703b40bdf57/pkcs11/src/api/object.rs#L256).
Check the source code line:

```
error!("C_SetAttributeValue() is supported only on CKA_ID");
```

The only way you can do is to re-create the `DATA` object with new `Value` content.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It looks like the source code you linked is for the Nitrokey NetHSM, but I'm using the Nitrokey HSM 2 (https://shop.nitrokey.com/shop/nkhs2-nitrokey-hsm-2-7). They very well may have the same limitations, but I can't find the source code for it to confirm.

Comment: This is the limitation of PKCS#11 library.     
Have a look at the account of [Nitrokey](https://github.com/Nitrokey) - there are only one repository with PKCS#11.    
There are [reference](https://github.com/Nitrokey/nethsm-pkcs11/blob/13fa4922102ccec4f8c521e89d1c6703b40bdf57/pkcs11/src/backend/slot.rs#L28) to `config` file - here we can connect to selected device.